# angularjs watch jquery directive value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu, watch

I'm running into a bit trouble with $scope.$watch. The situation is I'm using this nice plugin to create a dropdown: 
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

in my view file, I have:

```
<select id="hid" multiple="multiple" name="hname">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

in my js controller file:

```
$('#hid').change(function() { $scope.hvalue = $(this).val() }).multipleSelect({ width: '20%', selectAll:false })

$scope.testwatch = []
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.hvalue
  }, function(value) {
      if(value) {
        $scope.testwatch = $scope.hvalue
      }
     }, true)
```

The problem is that when the the user changed the dropdown, $scope.hvalue is modified. However, the $watch function is never executed. Any idea why this happens?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I were to hazard I guess I would say, your **jquery change function isn't in the angular digest cycle.**

To implement your functionality, I would recommend using **ng-model** on your select tag and keep a watch on that ng-model like this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="hid" multiple="multiple" name="hname" ng-model="obj.hvalue">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.obj = {};
$scope.obj.hvalue = '';
$scope.$watch('obj.hvalue', function(newval, oldval) {
    console.log(newval);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Tarun! Can you give a little hint how to implement the ng-model functionality?

Comment: I have shown it in the answer? Thats all you have to do. Also create a plunker if you get stuck

Comment: actually I tried ng-model, but it obj.hvalue does not change. Not sure whether the multiple-select plugin support this feature...

Comment: Actually most would recommend not using jquery with angularjs. For the multiselect plugin you can use one of angular's multiselect.  As for the ng-model problem can you create a plunker so I can help you there?

Comment: I changed the watch a little. Try now.

Comment: No, it still does not work. I think the problem is in the dropdown plugin https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/blob/master/jquery.multiple.select.js even though I have no idea why...

Comment: where can we find the angularjs multiselect plugin? Does it support "select all" feature? sorry to ask dumb questions..

Comment: Yes here's a multiselect I myself used: http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/